# JS - List randomizer that remembers and displays result for 24 hours before resetting?

Tags: javascript, html

I am 110% new at any type of programming so I've been using Weebly to build a website for a little game (sort of). 
I need a randomizer that picks something randomly from a predefined list and then displays the result. As it is, it works really well and looks like this:

```js
<!--

var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "No sickness caught today! :)";
r_text[1] = "No sickness caught today! :)";
r_text[2] = "No sickness caught today! :)";
r_text[3] = "No sickness caught today! :)";
r_text[4] = "No sickness caught today! :)";
r_text[5] = "Caught Parasites";
r_text[6] = "Caught Parasites";
r_text[7] = "Caught Parasites";
r_text[8] = "Caught Common Cold";
r_text[9] = "Caught Food Poisoning";

var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random());

document.write("<br /><br /><br /><center><FONT SIZE=65><FONT COLOR='#000000'>" +
r_text[i]  + "</FONT></center><br /><br /><br />");

</script>
```

My question is; Is there any way to have it remember and display the same result for 24 hours before resetting? Perhaps at a predefined hour? As it is, it resets everytime the page is refreshed.

I know this is probably an idiotic question but.... :)

Comment: Just a heads up - code snippet doesn't work :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*See below for alternate solution without using localStorage*

Assuming you are writing this completely in the front-end (HTML & JavaScript) with no back-end that can save information, you can save this information in the browser's `localstorage`. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for full details on `localstorage`. But essentially, `localstorage` allows you to save information into the browser and it will remember it for eternity! So you can combine this with the [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), for example, you can go ahead and save the date that the app was last accessed, and if it's a new day, then calculate a new number! Here's the general code you'd use:

```
 localStorage.setItem('lastAccessedMS',Date.now());
 var dateObj = new Date(); //create a day object to get the day
 localStorage.setItem('lastAccessedDay',dateObj.getDay());
```

So this bit of code above essentially saves the date that this person last accessed it.

```
 var dateLastMS = localStorage.getItem('lastAccessedMS');
 var dateLastDay = localStorage.getItem('lastAccessedDay');
 var dateObj = new Date();
       if(dateLast >= 86400000 ||  dateObj.getDay() != dateLastDay){
                 //Change your random number 
       }
```

And this bit of code above checks to see when last a user used it, and if its been a day or is a new day, calculate a new random number!

A couple of things to note -

*Why use both milliseconds and day?* Well if we just used a different day, what happens if the user visits exactly one week apart? Then the week day would still be the same! `Date.getDay()` returns an int between 0-6, indicating ONLY which day of the week it is. Of course you can test for this in a different way (i.e. check the exact month/date/year and see if its been a day), but this is the way I chose to do it for no particular reason other than it was the first thing I thought of.

*Why 86400000?* Thats how many milliseconds in a day :D, so if it's been more than a day between visits, we will for sure generate a new number!

*Where am I saving this information?* ONLY in the user's browser. So two people using two different computer's will have different numbers generated.

If you have any questions, please let me know.

**Update: Alternate Solution**

So given that the code is embedded and that you probably don't have access to localStorage, we can write a little algorithm to determine a new day cycle still using `Date.now()`

In order to do so, we're essentially going to use modulus (remainders) to figure out a cycle of days between time. The `Date.now()` function returns in milliseconds, the time that has passed since January 1st, 1970 I believe? Something like that. But let's say you have X number of random cases, and so you want to generate a number between 0 and X-1 (In your case above, X would be 10).

We would first have to determine how many days have gone by. We can calculate this with: `Date.now() / 86400000`

Ok, this gives us an ugly decimal, so lets just round down because it doesn't really matter. We can round down with the `Math.floor()` function.

So now we have `Math.floor(Date.now() / 86400000`

This will give us how many days have happened since whenever `Date.now()` was started. Now, all we have to do is modulus this number by X and it will give us a "random" number, so your final expression is:

`Math.floor(Date.now() / 86400000) % X` <-- plug in 10 for X

**HOWEVER** This isn't really "random", nor a true solution; it's merely a hack. It generates 0 on the first day, 1 on the second day, 2 on the third day.. etc to 9 on the tenth day, and then back to 0 on the 11th day. But it's really the best (that I can think of at least) we can do without the ability to save any information from the previous session.

**In order for this to seem more random**, I'd recommend generating a massive, randomly generated pattern for your X cases, so for an user, it won't seem like a static pattern, and be random enough to serve your purpose. What I mean is in your array of cases for, for example, 10 different possible cases, assign 0-9 randomly to 300 different slots and have your X value be 300 and each day would go to the next one in the 300 - length array, if that makes sense. This was long and probably a bit confusing, so if you need clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

On a small side note, if you plan on going further with programming and/or this game, I'd recommend looking into not using a service like Weebly that merely provides a template, but rather learn some HTML/JavaScript/PHP from CodeAcademy.com and build your own little website from scratch, because this way you'll be able to have a backend (server basically) to remember all the information you'd ever need!

Comment: This is great and everything mentioned makes sense. There's one thing i can't really figure out and i have a feeling it might be because of the limitations of using Weebly. The script is an embedded code (since weebly does everything else on it's own). So my next question would be; How do i get it to remember and display the random item it generates? I've been searching for the past hour for an answer. Is it even possible on an embedded code? Thank you for all the help! :)

Comment: @Bunyup ahhhh i see, check back later tonight, I think I might have a solution :)

Comment: @Bunyip updated solution :) really long, so if you need any clarification, please ask

Comment: This is brilliant (and not at all confusing) and works perfectly for what I need! It's a great workaround

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage for this. See the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Basically you could store the random number along with a timestamp of when it was generated. Then your code could check if there exists a random number that is still valid in localStorage, otherwise generate a new one and save it.

(Another option is to use some server to give you the number, but that is a bit more complicated to get started with.)